# Tutorial on onpen_exchange rate

Tags: android, json

I am working on a currency calculator app in android and I am using the open-exchange rate api.I am having problems on how to call the json elements (Currencies),I need a json script that I can use to to display all the currencies and their values. The tricky part is how to get the currency part only.please help.

```
{
"disclaimer": "Exchange rates provided by [...]",
"license": "Data collected and blended [...]",
"timestamp": 1319730758,
"base": "USD",
"rates": {
    "AED": 3.672626,
    "AFN": 48.3775,
    "ALL": 110.223333,
    "AMD": 409.604993,
    /* 160 fx rates available - see currencies.json */
    "YER": 215.035559,
    "ZAR": 8.416205,
    "ZMK": 4954.411262,
    "ZWL": 322.355011
}
}
```

Thanks